# How to extract last occurrence of character in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to extract a particular part of the string.

Input String : `$str = /wave=1/sin2=1/sin1=2/sin0=3`

Output String : `$str = /wave=1/sin2=1/sin1=2`

Method 1 :

`@waveSplitArray = split /\//,$str;`

`$lastOccuranceOfWave = pop @waveSplitArray;`

How to use regex to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this method also

```
my $str = '/wave=1/sin2=1/sin1=2/sin0=3';

my ($st2) = $str =~m{(.+)/};

print $st2;
```

`{(.+)/}`

Here `{}` works like delimiter `//` (Don't confused with quantifier for example`\d{n}`)

And `.` matches any character except new line and making this as to match 1 or more times using the `+` quantifier then it will matches till the END (Because `+` is  greedy quantifier, check the steps [here](https://regex101.com/r/iz8ScK/1/debugger)), then it will back track for the `/`, when it is find the `/` back track will terminate. And storing into the capturing group `()`, and capturing group will store into the `$st2` variable.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iz8ScK/1)

Comment: Can you explain ($st2) = $str =~m{(.+)/};  please

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use a greedy quantifier with a "keep" flag `\K`

If you want to keep the value of `$str` and put the result in a new variable

```
my $s2 = $str =~ s|.*\K/.*||r;
```

or

```
( my $s2 = $str ) =~ s|.*\K/.*||;
```

If you want to modify the original string, then it's just

```
$str =~ s|.*\K/.*||;
```

Comment: another solution may be just `[^/]*$`

Comment: @Nahuel: You mean `$str =~ s|/[^/]*$||`? I'm sticking with my version thanks.

Comment: or more exactly `($last) = $str =~ m|[^/]*$|g`, to get the last like pop does

Comment: @Nahuel: I'm not sure what you're trying to do there. That will leave `$last` set to `/sin0=3` and leave `$str` untouched. The OP is asking for the contents *before* that last segment. The `/g` modifier is rather odd, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/(.*\/)[^\/]*/
```

and you'll have the desired pattern in `$1`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6bocOB/1/)

Comment: The result doesn't match the OP's requirement, and the `[^\/]*` has no effect at all.